# How to parse a dynamic dom element?

Tags: python, parsing, phantomjs, innerhtml

I want to make a parser for scraping price, however I can't find the working method of parsing innerHTML

I don't know why, but selenium (getAttribute(innerHTML)), phantomjs (page.evaluation function(){return document.ElementToParse.innerHTML}) and  scrapy-splash (loaded a webpage using WebPageEngine and parse html) don't work. All the time, result is empty "[]", null or webelement

I test my code on banggood's products and also on landing page but result is always the same.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.banggood.com/BlitzWolf-Ampcore-Turbo-TC10-3A-Durable-USB-Type-C-Charging-Data-Cable-p-1188424.html?rmmds=category&cur_warehouse=CN") #random url
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item_now_price"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
print(element)
```

and output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="b0593791-138b-4177-a8f3-e7983143824a", element="d08f4717-d3f1-4594-8f2b-1bf943deb9f9")>
```

when need something like:

```
6.59(or US$6.59)
```

i also tried

```
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name('item_now_price').getAttribute("innerHTML")
```

and

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('https://www.banggood.com/BlitzWolf-Ampcore-Turbo-TC10-3A-        Durable-USB-Type-C-Charging-Data-Cable-p-1188424.html?rmmds=category&cur_warehouse=CN', function(status) {

    var price = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementByClassName('item_now_price').innerHTML;
        });
console.log('price is ' + price);
phantom.exit();
});
```

but result is null and when i add

```
page.includeJs(/url/to/js)
```

terminal stops working

s

Comment: Welcome to Stack! If you could provide some more specific information about your problem rather than generalities it would be helpful. For example, provide a specific element with it's html you've tried this on, and a code example of what you've tried, the result you were expecting, and the result you got instead.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to insert the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the element in selenium, you can get the text of that element with `.text`

See the slight adjustment to your first example below:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item_now_price"))
    )
    print(element.text)
finally:
```

See if that gets the results you're looking for.

Comment: and can i ask you some question?

Comment: do you know any faster variant of parser?

Comment: just if I, for example, parse 10 thousand elements, then only opening and closing the browser will take a long time

Comment: If you have access to some type of API so you can avoid the UI, that's the way to go... If not you could also try a headless browser with selenium to speed things up, and try running in parallel. Those are things that you can research separately as the comments aren't a great place to address that. Hopefully it gets you on the right track. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again, you really helped me a lot. I wish you best of everything :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.banggood.com/BlitzWolf-Ampcore-Turbo-TC10-3A-Durable-USB-Type-C-Charging-Data-Cable-p-1188424.html?rmmds=category&cur_warehouse=CN") #random url
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "item_now_price"))
    ).text
finally:
    driver.quit()
print(element)
```