# Plain text to odt with dynamic elements

Tags: libreoffice, odt

I am trying to figure out a way to create odt files with dynamic elements from a plain text file and avoid using any kind of scripts. While doing some testing, I can easily convert an odt file to plain text using libre office command line tool. However, when trying to convert from plain text to odt format, dynamic elements are lost. I searched the documentation but nothing specifies the expected format when converting.

I tried using the command `libreoffice --convert-to odt sampleFile.txt` but dynamic elements are not recognized.

Considering the following .txt file that contains

`${Parent.child}`

Can I convert it to a working .odt file ?

UPDATE:

I was able to do so using the XML format but it is not the desired way of doing this because the XML format requires/generate a lot of elements.

Sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<office:document xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:officeooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/office" xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table" xmlns:drawooo="http://openoffice.org/2010/draw" xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0" xmlns:loext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:office:xmlns:loext:1.0" xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0" xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" office:version="1.2" office:mimetype="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text">
 <office:meta><meta:document-statistic meta:character-count="108" meta:image-count="0" meta:object-count="0" meta:page-count="1" meta:paragraph-count="5" meta:table-count="0" meta:word-count="5"/><dc:date>2021-09-02T10:44:35</dc:date><meta:editing-duration>PT00H00M00S</meta:editing-duration><meta:editing-cycles>1</meta:editing-cycles><meta:generator>LibreOffice/6.0.7.3$Linux_X86_64 LibreOffice_project/00m0$Build-3</meta:generator></office:meta>
 <office:settings>
  <config:config-item-set config:name="ooo:view-settings">
   <config:config-item config:name="ViewAreaTop" config:type="long">0</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="ViewAreaLeft" config:type="long">0</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="ViewAreaWidth" config:type="long">0</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="ViewAreaHeight" config:type="long">0</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="ShowRedlineChanges" config:type="boolean">true</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="InBrowseMode" config:type="boolean">false</config:config-item>
  </config:config-item-set>
  <config:config-item-set config:name="ooo:configuration-settings">
   <config:config-item config:name="PrintPaperFromSetup" config:type="boolean">false</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="PrintFaxName" config:type="string"/>
   <config:config-item config:name="PrintSingleJobs" config:type="boolean">false</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="PrintProspectRTL" config:type="boolean">false</config:config-item>
   <config:config-item config:name="PrintProspect" config:type="boolean">false</config:config-item>
   <!-- ... and more -->
  </config:config-item-set>
 </office:settings>
 <office:scripts>
  <office:script script:language="ooo:Basic">
   <ooo:libraries xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"/>
  </office:script>
 </office:scripts>
 <!-- ... truncated styles -->
 <office:body>
  <office:text>
   <text:sequence-decls>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/>
   </text:sequence-decls>
   <text:p text:style-name="Standard"><text:text-input text:description="jooscript">${Parent.child}</text:text-input></text:p>
  </office:text>
 </office:body>
</office:document>
```

Comment: This question is mostly about dynamic elements, so you should add a tag for that. Anyway, from a web search, it looks like some people are using [Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56115672/how-to-parse-a-dynamic-dom-element) to parse them. So write a script to parse the dynamic elements and then output to a text file. Then use LibreOffice to convert the result to ODT format.

Comment: @JimK There's currently no tags for dynamic elements and I don't have the reputation to create one. I am trying to avoid using any scripts since the goal is to be able to manually create or change a dynamic element from a text editor. I will add details in the question regarding this.